# opencv browser live streaming

Tags: c++, html, opencv

Currently, I am using OpenCV to record a lifestream from my webcam. I now want to display that in a browser. I was thinking of using `VideoWriter` to write the video to a file, then somehow access that file from HTML5. Is this possible? Any other suggestions?

The following is the code I have.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
    if(!cap.isOpened()) { // check if we succeeded
        std::cout << "No camera found!\n";
    }

    namedWindow("Window",1);
    for(;;)
    {
        Mat frame;
        cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera

        imshow("Window", frame);
        char keypress;
        keypress = waitKey(30);
        if(keypress==27) break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As can be seen, I am displaying the live stream in a window, but, as said, I want a browser lifestream. Thanks.

Comment: Use a c++ library that does this, you may use WebRTC (with [Sourcey](http://sourcey.com/webrtc-native-to-browser-video-streaming-example/)) for example. Or maybe [Live555](http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/)